# Parser error in c++ Plugin for SonarQube

Tags: c++, sonarqube

I am getting a parser error when trying to run the commercial c++ plugin against my codebase.

```
[14:42:48][Step 12/12] 14:42:48.606 INFO  - Parse error in file F:\BuildAgent3\work\bc03ba0ff87f8a04\src\XXX\TestBools.cpp at line 23: 
[14:42:48][Step 12/12] 
[14:42:48][Step 12/12]    13:  using namespace NUnit :: Framework ;
[14:42:48][Step 12/12]    15:  namespace Core { namespace UnitTest {
[14:42:48][Step 12/12]    17:  [ TestFixture ]
[14:42:48][Step 12/12]    18:  public ref class TestBools {
[14:42:48][Step 12/12]    20:  public :
[14:42:48][Step 12/12]    22:  [ Test ]
[14:42:48][Step 12/12]    23:  void TestAll ( ) {
[14:42:48][Step 12/12]             ^
[14:42:48][Step 12/12]    25:  Bools b1 ( 20 , false ) ;
[14:42:48][Step 12/12]    26:  Bools b2 ( 19 , false ) ;
[14:42:48][Step 12/12]    28:  Assert :: IsTrue ( b1 . isAllEqual ( false )
```

I have tried searching but found no helpful information. I have all the latest versions of the plugins and core.

[I have already sent this link to the SonarSource support team for help - however I don't think that is free ;)]

Comment: I suspect you need to tell SonarQube to parse C++ using the MS extensions for Managed code: http://www.sonarqube.org/what-about-microsoft-component-extensions-for-c/

Comment: I am trying that now... 1 hour build ;) [I have already sent this link to the SonarSource support team for help]

Comment: Looks like that did not work. I selected c++CLI and still get the same issues...